# Issue with creating an array of objects in my project: expected unqualified-id

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

The purpose of this (obviously incomplete) project is just some practice with objects in my free time. I have run into the following error when testing the project and I am not sure exactly what the issue could be.

> "expected unqualified-id before ‘[’ token Competitor[] listOfCompetitors = new Competitor[10];"

Any help is much appreciated.

`main.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include competitor.cpp;

using namespace std;
int scoringMethod;
int numberOfCompetitors;

int main(int argc, char** argv){
cout<<"How would tou like to score the competition? (please enter an interger)"<<endl;
cout<< "1. Closest Total Points"<<endl<<"2. Closest Total Points Without Going Over" <<endl<<"3. Closest to team1 Score"<<endl<< "4. Closest to Opponent Score"<<endl<<endl;
cin>>scoringMethod;
cout<<endl<<"How many competitors do you have?"<<endl;
cin>>numberOfCompetitors;
Competitor[] listOfCompetitors = new Competitor[10];
string tempName;
int tempScore1, tempScore2;
for (int i = 0; i<numberOfCompetitors;i++){

    cout<<"Name of competitor number "<< i<<"?"<<endl;
    cin>>tempName;
    cout<<tempName<<"'s prediction for team1's score?"<<endl;
    cin>>tempScore1;
    cout<<tempName<<"'s prediction for the score of team1's opponent?"<<endl;
    cin>>tempScore2;

    listOfCompetitors[i] = new Competitor(tempName,tempScore1,tempScore2);
}    
cout <<endl<<"The program has reached the end successfully" << endl;
}
```

`competitor.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Competitor{
private:
string Name;
int team1Score;
int opponentScore;

public:
Competitor(){
    Name = "invalid";
    team1Score = opponentScore = 0;
}
Competitor(string nameIn, int inteam1Score, int inOpponentScore){
    Name=nameIn;
    team1Score=inteam1Score;
    opponentScore=inOpponentScore;
}
void printData(){
    cout<<this->Name<<"'s guess:"<<endl<<"team1: "<<team1Score<< "     Opponent: "<<opponentScore<<endl;
}
};
```

Comment: `Competitor[] listOfCompetitors = new Competitor[10];` -- C++ is not Java.  If you want a dynamic array -- `std::vector<Competitor> listOfCompetitors(numberOfCompetitors);`

Answer (score 0):

```
Competitor[] listOfCompetitors = new Competitor[10];
```

This is syntactically incorrect (for C/C++, at least) and is the reason why you're getting the error. If you want to dynamically allocate an array of `Competitors`, you could do

```
Competitor *listOfCompetitors = new Competitor[10];
```

and this will dynamically allocate an array of 10 `Competitors`.

---

A couple other issues with your code:

1. You're looping from `{0 ... numberOfCompetitors}` and accessing your `listOfCompetitors` array at each turn. What if `numberOfCompetitors` ≥ 10? Accessing `listOfCompetitors[i]` for `i` ≥ 10 becomes UB, or **undefined behaviour**.
2. The following line will cause a memory leak, if at all compile.

   listOfCompetitors[i] = new Competitor(tempName,tempScore1,tempScore2);

The type of `listOfCompetitors[i]` is `Competitor`, but `new Competitor(...)` will return a type of `Competitor*` (pointer to a `Competitor`). Thus, the `new` here isn't necessary. This should suffice:

```
listOfCompetitors[i] = Competitor(tempName, tempScore1, tempScore2);
```

3. You're not deleting any dynamically-allocated memory. Every time you use `new`, you need to remember to use `delete`, or else there will be memory-leaks. (There are certain exceptions to this, but not in the majority of C++.) You'll want to *deallocate* `listOfCompetitors`.

So after you've finished using `listOfCompetitors` (after the for-loop, maybe), do

```
delete []listOfCompetitors;
```

4. `#include competitor.cpp;` that shouldn't compile . Use quotations marks around non-standard-library filenames you're including: `#include "competitor.cpp"`.

---

As suggested in the comments, you can make use of [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) or [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) STL containers. They're easier to work with when it comes to dynamic arrays and do all the memory-management for you. (Also because you tagged your question with C++11 , STL containers would be a solid place to work towards.)

I strongly suggest [picking up a C++ book to read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and/or taking online tutorials to nail the fundamentals of dynamically-allocating memory, arrays, and whatnot.